# How to write in an array and perform calculations

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following code that writes in a .txt file of three grades comma delimited by 10 rows. (each row looks like this, 94,57,84,) This code works fine for writing in the file but I do not know how to make it average the scores. I definitely need it to average the 30 scores that are put in a textbox, but I would like for it to average each row as well. My GUI does this when I manually run the program but not when I pull in the text file that I made. Here is my code. The first part will be my write in code and the second will be all my code. Thanks for any helpful suggestions.

Here is the code straight from the book. All I did was add two buttons and code for these two buttons which are at the very end. I also addes Import system IO before the class and A public dim statement of Dim filename as string. It will write in without diff but when I call the submitbutton it throes an error at "grades(studentCount,0)=Concert.toInt32(test1TestBox.Text) so I added just the array code line 3,4,5 from the bottom. That ives me a Average calculation of "0" though. Here is the code straight from the book except display and open button code

```
       Imports System.IO ' using classes from this namespace

Public Class GradeReport
Dim fileName As String ' name of file containing account data
Dim grades(9, 2) As Integer ' stores 10 students' grades on 3 tests
Dim studentCount As Integer = 0 ' number of students entered

' display heading in gradeListBox
Private Sub GradeReport_Load(sender As Object,
   e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' headings row for gradesListBox
    gradesListBox.Items.Add(vbTab & vbTab & "Test 1" & vbTab &
       "Test 2" & vbTab & "Test 3" & vbTab & "Average")
End Sub

' process one student's grades
Private Sub submitButton_Click(sender As Object,
   e As EventArgs) Handles submitButton.Click

    ' retrieve the student's grades
    grades(studentCount, 0) = Convert.ToInt32(test1TextBox.Text)
    grades(studentCount, 1) = Convert.ToInt32(test2TextBox.Text)
    grades(studentCount, 2) = Convert.ToInt32(test3TextBox.Text)

    ' begin creating String containing the student's grades and average
    Dim output As String = "Student " & studentCount & vbTab

    ' append each test grade to the output
    For column = 0 To grades.GetUpperBound(1)
        ' if the Letter RadioButton is checked
        If letterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
            ' append letter grade to the output
            output &= vbTab & LetterGrade(grades(studentCount, column))
        Else
            ' append number grade to the output
            output &= vbTab & grades(studentCount, column)
        End If
    Next

    ' append the student's test average to the output
    output &= vbTab & CalculateStudentAverage(studentCount)

    gradesListBox.Items.Add(output) ' add output to the ListBox
    studentCount += 1 ' update number of students entered
    averageLabel.Text = CalculateClassAverage() ' display class average
    DisplayBarChart() ' display the current grade distribution

    ' clear the input TextBoxes and set focus to first TextBox
    test1TextBox.Clear()
    test2TextBox.Clear()
    test3TextBox.Clear()
    test1TextBox.Focus()

    ' limit number of students
    If studentCount = grades.GetUpperBound(0) + 1 Then
        inputGradesGroupBox.Enabled = False ' disable GroupBox's controls
    End If
End Sub ' submitButton_Click

' handles Numeric and Letter RadioButtons' CheckChanged events
Private Sub RadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object,
   e As EventArgs) _
   Handles numericRadioButton.CheckedChanged,
      letterRadioButton.CheckedChanged

    ' if there are grades to display, call DisplayClassGrades
    If studentCount > 0 Then
        DisplayClassGrades()
    End If
End Sub ' RadioButton_CheckedChanged

' calculates a student's test average
Function CalculateStudentAverage(row As Integer) As String
    Dim gradeTotal As Integer = 0 ' student's total grade

    ' sum the grades for the student
    For column = 0 To grades.GetUpperBound(1)
        gradeTotal += grades(row, column)
    Next

    Dim studentAverage As String = String.Empty ' output string

    ' calculate the student's test average
    If letterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
        studentAverage =
           LetterGrade(gradeTotal / (grades.GetUpperBound(1) + 1))
    Else
        studentAverage = String.Format("{0:F}",
           (gradeTotal / (grades.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)))
    End If

    Return studentAverage ' return the student's average
End Function ' CalculateStudentAverage

' calculates the class average
Function CalculateClassAverage() As String
    Dim classTotal As Integer = 0 ' class's total grade

    ' loop through all rows that currently contain grades
    For row = 0 To studentCount - 1
        ' loop through all columns
        For column = 0 To grades.GetUpperBound(1)
            classTotal += grades(row, column) ' add grade to total
        Next column
    Next row

    Dim classAverage As String = String.Empty ' output string

    ' if the Letter RadioButton is checked, return letter grade
    If letterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
        classAverage = LetterGrade(classTotal /
           (studentCount * (grades.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)))
    Else ' return numeric grade
        classAverage = String.Format("{0:F}", (classTotal /
           (studentCount * (grades.GetUpperBound(1) + 1))))
    End If

    Return classAverage ' return the class average
End Function ' CalculateClassAverage

' determines a letter grade corresponding to a numeric grade
Function LetterGrade(grade As Double) As String
    Dim output As String ' the letter grade to return

    ' determine the correct letter grade
    Select Case grade
        Case Is >= 90
            output = "A"
        Case Is >= 80
            output = "B"
        Case Is >= 70
            output = "C"
        Case Is >= 60
            output = "D"
        Case Else
            output = "F"
    End Select

    Return output ' return the letter grade
End Function ' LetterGrade

' display the grades for all students entered
Sub DisplayClassGrades()
    gradesListBox.Items.Clear() ' clear the ListBox

    ' add the header to the ListBox
    gradesListBox.Items.Add(vbTab & vbTab & "Test 1" & vbTab &
       "Test 2" & vbTab & "Test 3" & vbTab & "Average")

    ' loop through all the rows
    For row = 0 To studentCount - 1
        Dim output As String = "Student " & row & vbTab

        ' loop through all the columns
        For column = 0 To grades.GetUpperBound(1)
            If letterRadioButton.Checked = True Then
                ' add letter grade to output string
                output &= vbTab & LetterGrade(grades(row, column))
            Else
                ' add number grade to output string
                output &= vbTab & (grades(row, column))
            End If
        Next column

        ' add the student's average to the output
        output &= vbTab & CalculateStudentAverage(row)

        ' add the output to the ListBox
        gradesListBox.Items.Add(output)
    Next row

    ' update the class average
    averageLabel.Text = CalculateClassAverage()
End Sub ' DisplayClassGrades

' display a bar chart of the grade distribution
Sub DisplayBarChart()
    barChartListBox.Items.Clear() ' remove current items

    ' stores frequency of grades in each range of 10 grades
    Dim frequency(10) As Integer

    ' for each grade, increment the appropriate frequency
    For row = 0 To studentCount - 1
        For column = 0 To grades.GetUpperBound(1)
            frequency(grades(row, column) \ 10) += 1
        Next column
    Next row

    ' for each grade frequency, display bar of asterisks
    For count = 0 To frequency.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim bar As String ' stores the label and bar

        ' create bar label ( "00-09: ", ..., "90-99: ", "100: " )
        If count = 10 Then
            bar = String.Format("{0, 5:D}: ", 100)
        Else
            bar = String.Format("{0, 2:D2}-{1, 2:D2}: ",
               count * 10, count * 10 + 9)
        End If

        ' append bar of asterisks
        For stars = 1 To frequency(count)
            bar &= ("*")
        Next

        barChartListBox.Items.Add(bar) ' display bar
    Next count
End Sub ' DisplayBarChart

Private Sub Open_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Open.Click

    ' opens a file in which accounts are stored

    Dim result As DialogResult ' stores result of Open dialog

    ' create dialog box enabling user to open file
    Using fileChooser As New OpenFileDialog()
        result = fileChooser.ShowDialog()
        fileName = fileChooser.FileName ' get specified file name
    End Using ' automatic call to fileChooser.Dispose() occurs here

    ' if user did not click Cancel, enable Buttons
    If result <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Display.Enabled = True

    End If
End Sub ' OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click


Private Sub Display_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Display.Click

    ' display accounts of specified type

    Dim fileReader As StreamReader = Nothing

    ' read and display file information
    Try
        gradesListBox.Text = "The accounts are:" & vbCrLf

        ' open file for reading
        fileReader = New StreamReader(fileName)

        ' read file and display lines that match the balance type
        Do While Not fileReader.EndOfStream ' while not end of file
            Dim line As String = fileReader.ReadLine() ' read line
            Dim fields() As String = line.Split(","c) ' split into fields
            'Dim fields() As String = line.Split(CChar(","))

            ' get data from fields array

            Dim Test1 As String = fields(0)             'Integer = Convert.ToInt32(fields(0))
            Dim Test2 As String = fields(1)
            Dim Test3 As String = fields(2)

            ' If ShouldDisplay(balance, accountType) Then
            gradesListBox.Items.Add(vbTab & vbTab & Test1 & vbTab &
               Test2 & vbTab & Test3 & vbCrLf)

        Loop
    Catch ex As IOException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Read File", "Error",
           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally ' ensure that file gets closed
        If fileReader IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                fileReader.Close() ' close StreamReader
            Catch ex As IOException
                MessageBox.Show("Error closing file", "Error",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End If
    End Try


    ' submitButton.PerformClick


    studentCount += 1 ' update number of students entered
    averageLabel.Text = CalculateClassAverage() ' display class average
    DisplayBarChart() ' display the current grade distribution



End Sub ' submitButton_Click
```

End Class ' GradeReport

Comment: When you read the file back, you dont call your calc routines, but juat add the text to a listbix.

Comment: How do I call my calc routines, I have tried absoletuly everything and cant get it to work. I have close to 40 hours in just this one part. I think I was close once

Comment: if you put everything back where it goes (too hard to tell from here what is student and what is class related) you should just be able to do whatever it is that calculated it initially.  Unfortunately, that seems to be a button click, so once everything is back exactly where it came from, do `ButtonName.PerformClick`  using the button name you want.  you may have to do several to walk thru students then the class to reconstruct everything ... or when you save, you could save the current averages so you dont have to recalculate

Comment: what about the functions, is there a way to pull those in

Comment: Some (all???) of that will happen already.  e.g. `submitButton` calls the `LetterGrade` and `CalculateStudentAverage` anything else you need can be called when you reload the data just like before.

Comment: to me it look like I didn't name the array anything once it came back in

Comment: What is the question? And please do something about the wall of code. Nobody wants to look at that.

Comment: The question would be How do I get my inputfile.txt to calculate an averaged based off the 30 grades

Comment: my teacher said that I was reading the file and not loading the file. What is the differene

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher probably means that the data from the file is only being displayed and not being stored.  See if something like this helps:

```
Private Sub Display_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Display.Click

    ' display accounts of specified type

    Dim fileReader As StreamReader = Nothing

    ' read and display file information
    Try
        gradesListBox.Text = "The accounts are:" & vbCrLf

        ' open file for reading
        fileReader = New StreamReader(fileName)

        ' read file and display lines that match the balance type
        Dim Counter As Integer = 0
        Do While Not fileReader.EndOfStream ' while not end of file
            Dim line As String = fileReader.ReadLine() ' read line
            Dim fields() As String = line.Split(","c) ' split into fields
            'Dim fields() As String = line.Split(CChar(","))

            ' get data from fields array

            For I = 0 To 2
                Grades(Counter,I) = Integer.Parse(fields(I))
            Next


            ' If ShouldDisplay(balance, accountType) Then
            gradesListBox.Items.Add(vbTab & vbTab & Grades(Counter,0) & vbTab &
               Grades(Counter,1) & vbTab & Grades(Counter,2) & vbCrLf)
            If Counter <= 8 Then
                 Counter += 1
            Else
               Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Catch ex As IOException
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Read File", "Error",
           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally ' ensure that file gets closed
        If fileReader IsNot Nothing Then
            Try
                fileReader.Close() ' close StreamReader
            Catch ex As IOException
                MessageBox.Show("Error closing file", "Error",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End If
    End Try


    ' submitButton.PerformClick


    studentCount += 1 ' update number of students entered
    averageLabel.Text = CalculateClassAverage() ' display class average
    DisplayBarChart() ' display the current grade distribution



End Sub ' submitButton_Click
```

Of course this will only fill the array to the size you've set.  If you want the data to be more dynamic, use a List(Of) instead.

Also this assumes that the data in the file is strongly consistent and doesn't verify the data.